# Wreath Product Notation

Tags: group-theory, permutations, wreath-product

i have a doubt about the Wreath Product Notation, for example on Wikipedia, or most internet pages (also some questions here on Mathstackexchange) i find :

The wreath product  $A ≀  B$ of A by B is the semidirect product K ⋊ H, where K is a direct product of $|B|$ copies of A.

But then i find in some papers something like:

The wreath product A ≀ B is the semidirect product $B^A ⋊ A$, where A acts on $B^A$ by shifts

Which says the exact opposite...
So i´m a Little confusing about the notation, which one should i use? or there is something that i´m missing? 
When i see $A ≀  B$ in a random paper i have to check wether it`s one definition or the other one..

Comment: Pick one and be explicit about what you mean by the notation.

Comment: And yes, if you read that in a paper and the author does not explicittly tell you which she means, then you have to figure it out yourself.

Comment: It's similar to the way some people talk about an extension of a group $G$ by a group $H$ and expect everybody else to know what they mean.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, yeah guess i`ll have to be explicit, but i wanted to ask before, maybe there was some consent about the notation. About figure out the groups, sometimes i kinda hard cause usually A ≀ B and B ≀ A, both appear in the same cases

Comment: Similar to Derek's comment, I have seen uses where semidirect product is "backwards" from the common meaning.